# Decoding/Encoding Href Links

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

How can I get the result of `expected` to return a readable string? In other words, when given `/wiki/Cookbook:Cao_l%E1%BA%A7u`, it should return `/wiki/Cookbook:Cao_lầu`.

**Note**: I'm running on Python 2.7.2

```
import urllib

test_array = [
    '/wiki/Cookbook:Bulgarian_Meatball_Soup_(Supa_Topcheta)',
    '/wiki/Cookbook:Campfire_S%27mores',
    '/wiki/Cookbook:Candied_Almonds_(Br%C3%A4nda_mandlar)',
    '/wiki/Cookbook:Chicken_%26_Pasta_Alfredo',   
    '/wiki/Cookbook:Cozido_%C3%A0_Portuguesa'
]

actual = [urllib.unquote(i).decode('utf-8') for i in test_array]

assert '/wiki/Cookbook:Bulgarian_Meatball_Soup_(Supa_Topcheta)' == actual[0]
assert "/wiki/Cookbook:Campfire_S'mores" == expected[1]
assert '/wiki/Cookbook:Candied_Almonds_(Brända_mandlar)' == actual[2]
assert '/wiki/Cookbook:Chicken_&_Pasta_Alfredo' == actual[3]
assert '/wiki/Cookbook:Cozido_à_Portuguesa' == actual[4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specified the unicode literals (prefixing `u`) instead of string literals, because the [`str.decode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) returns `unicode` object.

```
assert u'/wiki/Cookbook:Bulgarian_Meatball_Soup_(Supa_Topcheta)' == expected[0]
assert u"/wiki/Cookbook:Campfire_S'mores" == expected[1]
assert u'/wiki/Cookbook:Candied_Almonds_(Brända_mandlar)' == expected[2]
assert u'/wiki/Cookbook:Chicken_&_Pasta_Alfredo' == expected[3]
assert u'/wiki/Cookbook:Cozido_à_Portuguesa' == expected[4]
```

BTW, I would give `expected` a different name like `actual` or `got`. (String literals are expected outcome, right?)

Comment: I need the array to contain exactly those exact strings. Essentially, if you were to loop through ```expected``` and print each element you would see the string representation. I need them as strings so I can split them by ":" to just extract the recipe names. That's the result I need in ```expected```. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @TheGrayFox, If you want string (bytestring), then drop `.decode('utf-8')`.  http://ideone.com/ZV34et

Comment: ```expected[3]``` returns ```/wiki/Cookbook:Candied_Almonds_(Br\xc3\xa4nda_mandlar)``` which isn't ```/wiki/Cookbook:Candied_Almonds_(Brända_mandlar)```.

Comment: @TheGrayFox, That's how python represent characters that is not printable (ASCII). Try to print them (not the whole list, but each items): http://ideone.com/YM9VKS

Comment: @TheGrayFox, In other word, `assert '/wiki/Cookbook:Candied_Almonds_(Br\xc3\xa4nda_mandlar)' == '/wiki/Cookbook:Candied_Almonds_(Brända_mandlar)'`

Comment: I see, my mistake for not seeing that. The only thing is, I want the list comp to create those exact strings in your stdout based on the last link. I'm going to use these these strings to create key elements inside of a dictionary. I'm going to be referencing these by exact key names. Will it be in readable ascii format when I zip these values inside of a dict?

Comment: @TheGrayFox, No they will not. They will print what you want only when they are printed individually.

Comment: That's where I'm stuck because I need them to be in that format. I knew this would be tough...

Comment: Example: ```{'Candied_Almonds_(Brända_mandlar)': 'http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cookbook:Candied_Almonds_(Br%C3%A4nda_mandlar)'}```. The key needs to be exactly that.

Comment: @TheGrayFox, To use where?

Comment: To use with something called jq. It will look at a JSON file I create based on that a key that points to a name, and a value that points to the exact url.

Comment: @TheGrayFox, You can still access the key-value with `\xOO`-style string literal: `{'Candied_Almonds_(Brända_mandlar)': 'http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cookbook:Candied_Almonds_(Br%C3%A4nda_mandlar)'}['Candied_Almonds_(Brända_mandlar)']`

Comment: @TheGrayFox, JSON? Why don't you use `json.dumps`? http://ideone.com/SM6yjN , http://ideone.com/CfFMph

Comment: @TheGrayFox, BTW, it don't need to be exactly `..ä..` if the `jq` is properly parser JSON. `...\uxxxx...` should work.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, and the examples. You're right!